# PHP array from 17 - 395

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array with the values from 17 - 395, but I dont feel like typing in each number, there has gotta be a better way to do this...is there?

```
$x = array(17, 18, 19, 20,... 395);
```

Thanks,
J

What I am looking to do is this

```
$x = array(17, 395);

foreach ($x as $y => $z){
    echo 'This is number '. $z . '';
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [range](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

```
$x = range(17, 395);
```

Comment: $x = array(range(17, 295)); like that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Loops - [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)
If you do $array[] = $x, it automatically adds $x to the end of the array.